# Perl regex to extract floating number

Tags: regex, perl

I need to modify someone's Perl script, and I am not familiar with Perl at all.

There is a scalar variable `$var`, whose value is a floating point number possibly followed by junk. I need to extract the floating point number.

The number is in non-exponential format: DDD[.DDD], and has no sign.

Fractional part may be missing. Integer part is not missing (`.123` is just junk)

If the variable starts with junk (in particular, sign or decimal point), I need to extract empty string.

Examples:

```
-123.456 ==> ""
123. ==> "123"
123.456.789 ==> "123.456"
123.456junk ==> "123.456"
123junk ==> "123"
123.junk ==> "123"     # strip the dot if no fraction
.123 ==> ""
junk ==> ""
000.000 ==> "000.000"
```

Could someone provide a solution, I guess it should be: `$var =~ s/REGEX_EXPRESSION`, but I cannot figure out what `REGEX_EXPRESSION` should be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your update, the expression you need is:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

- `^\d+` Match digits at start of string.
- `(?:` Start of non capturing group.
- `\.\d+` Match a literal `.`, followed by digits.
- `)?` Close non capturing group making it optional.

Check the expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/SgbDW0/1).

A Perl example:

```
$var = "123.456.789";
print "old $var\n";
$var =~ /(^\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/;
print "new $1\n";
```

*Prints:*

```
old 123.456.789
new 123.456
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am trying suggested expressions, I guess I am not using them correctly in Perl:

```
my $var = "123.456.66";
print "old $var\n";
$var =~ s/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?//;
print "new $var\n";
```

Output:

```
$perl main.pl
old 123.456.66
new .66
```

Comment: Hey bud, if you're going to just replace the _junk_ in one step, use this [$var =~ s/(?m)^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?.*/$1/g](https://regex101.com/r/FFhOdN/1)

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, you need to extract the first one or two groups of digits from a string. Like so.

```
123.456.789  # 123.456
123.456abc   # 123.456
123abc       # 123
abc123       # nothing
```

The regex would look like this, expanded out for a better explanation.

```
qr{
  (
    \d+ 
    (?: \.\d+ )?
  )
}x;
```

`qr` is the regex quoting operator. Using `x` means to ignore spaces so things are more readable.

`\d` matches digits. `+` says to match 1 or more of the preceding. So `\d+` is 1 or more digits.

`()` captures the contents.

`(?:)` groups the contents but does not capture.

`?` says to capture 0 or 1 of the preceding. It means it's optional.

So `(?: \.\d+ )?` means a dot followed by some digits is optional.

You'd use it like so.

```
my $str = "123.456abc";
my $digits_re = qr{ (\d+ (?: \.\d+ )?) }x;
my($digits) = $str =~ $digits_re;
print $digits;
```

For more information see the [Perl Regex Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and you can play with it on [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/ZAFrhB/1).