# Perl REGEXP for float

Tags: regex, perl

New to Perl, I try using REGEXP to get parameters from file lines.

The corresponding line can take several forms :

```
(ATT: X:0.0 Y:0.0)
(ATT: X:0 Y:2.70823)
(bch x1.00003 y0.99988)
```

the goal is to retrieve the X and Y values.

I wrote this

```perl
(($x, $xd, $y, $yd) = ($v =~ m/[xX][^0-9+-]*([+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?)[^0-9+-yY]*[yY][^0-9+-]*([+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?)/ ))
```

It works but I have to use 4 vars to achieve it

Is there a better way?

Furthermore, if we now consider that X and Y values can be reversed in the line for example

```
(ATT: Y:0.0 X:0.0)
```

My solution does not work any more... Is there a solution that could work in all cases?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have a look at this https://regex101.com/r/C24sBA/1/

Comment: from your regex it seems that you don't want values from `bch x1.00003 y0.99988`. Is it?

Comment: I want it to work with all the shapes the line can have. So for this one I want to get $x=1.00003 and $y=0.99988

Comment: Consider the `decimal` regex from [Regexp::Common::number](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::number)

Comment: @Toto I'm not sure if I agree with the verdict "duplicate". The other question is different and the accepted answer only solves one part of OPs problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# NOTE: change this if you need it to be more strict, e.g. should not match "0"
my $regex_float    = qr/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/;

# match: white space   + one letter      (group 1) +
#        (optional) :  + floating number (group 2)
my $regex_variable = qr/\s+(\w):?(${regex_float})/;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    #         applied multiple times
    # returns list: g1, g2, g1, g2, ...
    my %values =
        map { uc }  # upper case variable name
        ($_ =~ /${regex_variable}/g);

    my $x = $values{X} // die "can't find X on line '$_'\n";
    my $y = $values{Y} // die "can't find Y on line '$_'\n";

    print "$_ -> (${x}, ${y})\n";
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
(ATT: X:0.0 Y:0.0)
(ATT: X:0 Y:2.70823)
(bch x1.00003 y0.99988)
(ATT: Y:3.0 X:4.0)
Time-space continuum with lazy and x: nast y: generator t:1.0 Y2.1 z3.2 x:4.3
```

Test output:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
(ATT: X:0.0 Y:0.0) -> (0.0, 0.0)
(ATT: X:0 Y:2.70823) -> (0, 2.70823)
(bch x1.00003 y0.99988) -> (1.00003, 0.99988)
(ATT: Y:3.0 X:4.0) -> (4.0, 3.0)
Time-space continuum with lazy and x: nast y: generator t:1.0 Y2.1 z3.2 x:4.3 -> (4.3, 2.1)
```

NOTE: float regex taken from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732041/perl-regex-to-extract-floating-number)

Comment: still need to work on the reverse case though...

Comment: Reverse case handled too now. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick (switch the comments to test each):

```
$ cat file.pl
use strict;

#my $str = '(ATT: X:0.0 Y:0.0)';
#my $str = '(ATT: X:0 Y:2.70823)';
#my $str = '(bch x1.00003 y0.99988)';
my $str = '(bch y1.00003 x0.99988)';

my %hash;

if ( $str =~ /([xy]):*([\d.]+)\s+([xy]):*([\d.]+)/i ) {
   $hash{lc($1)} = $2;
   $hash{lc($3)} = $4;

   print "X = ". $hash{'x'} . "\n";
   print "Y = ". $hash{'y'} . "\n";
}


$ perl file.pl
X = 0.99988
Y = 1.00003
```